# .elf file getting deleted in eclipse cube ide for embedded c/c++

Tags: eclipse, raspberry-pi-pico, blink

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkAbW.png)

i was trying to build a blink file in eclipse ide.It works with gitbash and cmd prompt and in VS code
some issue has occured so tried it with eclipse but only upto hex file is build when it reach in elf file it shows an error '..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.